# Axios Retry for success response interceptor

Tags: javascript, api, axios, interceptor, axios-retry

I have situation where I want to retry the request if status code for API response is 202 after the specified time.

In axios success interceptor, I am doing like

```
    function axiosRetrySuccessInterceptor(response) {
         const { status, config } = response;
         // Retry the request on http status code 202
         if (status === 202 ) {

            return new Promise(() => {

               setTimeout(() => {

                  axios.request(config)

                }, 2000);
            });

         } else {

            // No need to do anything, take rest
            return Promise.resolve(response);
         }
    }

     
    // calling function
    axios.interceptors.response.use(axiosRetrySuccessInterceptor,axiosRetryInterceptor);
```

I want to clear the previous retry request if any other non 202 API calls.

I have added the clearTimeout as well but no success.

When I go back the previous screen, new API is called and but previous retry API still called. It doesn't stop.
Have tried something like below also using clearTimeout, but no success, instead it stop the retry

```
     var retry = setTimeout(() => {

        axios.request(config)

        clearTimeout(retry)
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you're not resolving your inner promise?

```
  function axiosRetrySuccessInterceptor(response) {
         const { status, data, config } = response;
         // Retry the request on http status code 202
         if (status === 202 ) {

            return new Promise((resolve) => {

               setTimeout(() => {

                  axios.request(config).then(resolve);

                }, data.retryAfter);
            });

         } else {

            // No need to do anything, take rest
            return Promise.resolve(response);
         }
    }
```

Comment: Have tried this way also, but it also doesn't stop the retry on going back

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'stop the retry on going back'

Comment: I want to stop the previous retry request, if any other API calls

Comment: You can't stop a request once it's happened.

Comment: If new request come which is not 202, it should stop the retry. right?

Comment: I want to clear the previous retry if new request comes

Comment: Have solved the clearsettimeout  problem, but when my request gives 200 success response, it is returning the previous retry object response. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
                const abc = setTimeout(() => {
                    axios.request(config).then(resolve);
                    clearTimeout(abc);
                }, data.retryAfter);
            });
```

@TKol Have tried this but didn't work